# What algorithm may be used to solve the re-assembly of shredded papers?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

I was once given this question in an interview:

> Suppose a piece of paper has 80 columns of alphabets with a fixed size font, and now the paper is shredded vertically, into 80 vertical pieces (so each piece can show a series of alphabets going down vertically), and there are 300 pages of such paper shredded total. Assume they are just English words with no proper names (for people / places). Find a method to reassemble all the papers and give the O() complexity time and space.

I proposed a solution where we take one piece of stripe, and go down the row to match for consecutive occurring alphabets, for a proper stripe. So we would build up a dictionary of all English words, for example, for the word `Apple`, that will mean `ap`, `pp`, `pl`, and `le` are all valid. And if we go down both stripes, we should expect most (or all) of them match with each other if they were adjacent.

But doing this way, it looks like it would be `(180 * 300)! = 24000!` (factorial) steps, before we can finish the task? I can only find a complicated paper about re-constructing non-fixed size font paper (and it seemed way too complicated for a 20 minute interview question), and [another paper that is not public](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7400627).  Is there a good solution to this problem?

(Actually, it seems that if it is not fixed size font, it is a easier problem?  Because we can just look at the left and right edge: along the left edge, for example, if there is ink, we call it as `1`, and no ink, we call it a `0`. Or we can just scan and collect data: from top edge, go down 3.232cm of blank space, and then 0.012cm of ink, and then 0.027cm of blank space, all the way down to the end of paper, and then we can create a signature.  If we do the signature for all `80 x 300` stripes, now we have `48000` signatures. Now we can actually just match the signatures up to tell which strips is adjacent to which stripe. So that would be a linear O(n) solution?)

Answer (score 2):

If the cuts are in the middle of letters, then I think your solution in the last paragraph is a good one.

If the cuts go between letters, then I think your approach of finding pairs of strips of papers is a good one.  I would start by finding all pairs of strips that could have been adjacent, based on which digraphs (pairs of characters) can appear in some word.  Then, I would try to extend to find all triples of strips that could have been adjacent: for each possible pair of adjacent strips $s_1,s_2$, find all $s_3$ such that $s_2,s_3$ is a pair of possible adjacent strips; then test whether if you past together $s_1,s_2,s_3$ that all trigraphs (triples of characters) can appear in some word.  Then, I would extend to 4-tuples of strips, filtering them based on 4-graphs of characters, and so on.  The worst-case complexity could be horrible in principle, but in practice I expect that you'll very quickly filter out all false matches, so running time will probably be very good.

For fun, you might enjoy reading about the [DARPA shredding challenge](https://archive.darpa.mil/shredderchallenge/index.html) ([summary on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DARPA_Shredder_Challenge_2011)).

Comment: if it is in between characters, would it be `24000!` (factorial)? It seems like even `70! = 1.19785716699699e100` would not make it practical... if the match is on average made half way through, then `24000! / 2` would still be not practically possible

Comment: correction: if on average, we can make a match half way through, it  should be `12000!`

Comment: @nopole, In practice, only a tiny fraction of all possible pairs of strips will be valid; and only a tiny fraction of all possible triples will be valid; and so on.  As I wrote, "The worst-case complexity could be horrible in principle, but in practice I expect that you'll very quickly filter out all false matches, so running time will probably be very good." I don't see much point in calculating precisely how horrible it could be; it's clear that it could be atrociously bad.

Comment: now is it true in real life, if we have got 24,000 pieces of stripes, and now we are holding one, just to match this one, it is not easy? We could be matching 24,000 stripe (12,000 match on average) before we get the match.

Comment: @nopole, my estimate is that less than half of all possible trigraphs are valid (appear somewhere in some English word).  If each paper has 50 lines of text on it, this suggests that a wrong triple might survive the filtering with probability only $1/2^{50}$, since every row must be valid, and there are 50 rows.  If you have 300 strips, there are $300^3 = 27M$ triples; as 27M is far far less than $1/2^{50}$, I expect that essentially no wrong triple will survive.

Comment: Nopole, a six year old child can easily put a 100 piece jigsaw puzzle together. It doesn’t take n! steps.

Comment: DW. For a _real_ challenge we have the East-German Stasi shredding challenge. Hundreds of black sacks filled with little bits of papers that they wanted to be kept secret.

Comment: @gnasher729 hold on a second... if it is a jigsaw puzzle, there is the luxury of: we know this top part of the puzzle is the blue sky. Now this piece is blue, so it is up above, and besides it has a little bit of color of the airplane, so we know it is to the top-right of the puzzle... so we greatly simplify the `100!`... so if we have 20 sections of `5!`, it is a lot more simpler

Answer (score 2):

So... for the fixed-size font problem, if it were me, I'd use a stochastic global optimisation method. Specifically, I would try to find the permutation of the columns which optimises the compressibility of the text if it were compressed using a static model (e.g. [PPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_by_partial_matching) or [DMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Markov_compression)) trained on English text.

I'd probably use [simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) to start with. I'd pick some mutation operations, one of which is "swap two columns", one of which is "move a column to a random other place", and one of which (chosen with low probability) is "restart with a random permutation", and then let Metropolis and Hastings do their thing.

I can't think of a good "crossover" operation off the top of my head, but if so, a [genetic algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) might also be appropriate.

The space usage is $O(nk)$ where $k$ is the population size that you want to retain. The run time is exponential in the worst case, but likely faster than most deterministic algorithms.